# react hooks callback function need to be clicked twice

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a following `JSX` and it behaving in a weird manner. I need to click the button twice to update the `setRows` hook.

```
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [fileName, setfileName] = useState('test.txt');

  const handleFilenameClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setfileName(e.target.value);
    async function anyNameFunction() {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/files/fileData/${fileName}`);
      setRows(response.data);
    }
    anyNameFunction();

  };

   <div className="list-group list-group-flush">
      {fileNames.map((file) => {
        return <input type="button" className="bg-light" onClick={handleFilenameClick} value={file}></input>
      })}
    </div>
```

> My problem is that when I click on my button it should set the `setRows` and update my grid. Currently I need to click twice for it to work. I am unable to figure out the exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const handleFilenameClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setfileName(e.target.value);
    async function anyNameFunction() {
      // use `e.target.value` directly because `setfileName` is async. 
     // so every time when you use it, you will always get it's previous value
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/files/fileData/${e.target.value}`);
      setRows(response.data);
    }
    anyNameFunction();

  };
```